# Div lowered instead of buttons

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to make a website that creates a design for websites. It will tell you the code you will need to make the site. I have a toolbar div that contains a table with 6 buttons. When I attempt to make the buttons lower down in the toolbar div, it moves the div down, and the buttons are still at some dozen pixels down from the top of the div. Here's my code:

```css
.toolbar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #444444;
}
#a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='toolbar'>
  <center>
    <table class='tools' id='a'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='text' id='a'>
            Add text
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='image' id='a'>
            Add image
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='table' id='a'>
            Add table
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='jsbutton' id='a'>
            Add button
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='addons' id='a'>
            Add-ons
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with this code, or are my requirements impossible?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. You may want to swap your use of classes and IDs.

Comment: The `<center>` element is deprecated in `HTML` try not to use it

Comment: It's always worked to use center. When I use text-align, it doesn't center to well for tables and divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use `padding`s and `margin`s, and drop the `toolbar` `height`.

By setting `padding` on the `toolbar`, all buttons is pushed down, and the by using `margin` on each `button`, they individually separate.

I changed the table to `display: inline-table;`, added `text-align: center;` to your `toolbar` so it's centered (as the `<center>` element is deprecated), and I also dropped the `id`'s, as they should be unique.

```css
.toolbar {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
}
.tools {
  display: inline-table;
}
.tools, .text, .image, .table, .jsbutton, .addons {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='toolbar'>
    <table class='tools'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='text'>
            Add text
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='image'>
            Add image
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='table'>
            Add table
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='jsbutton'>
            Add button
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='addons'>
            Add-ons
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Everyone's answers are the same, but this one was extremely informative and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `padding`, not `margin`. Margin is offset outside the div, padding is offset inside the div. Something like this will push the buttons down:

```
.toolbar {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

This might help for understanding the box model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: I think this'll work, I don't have time to test it right now. I sure hope it does!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. I hope this will help you.

http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/jqbmgj

```
.toolbar {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding to control the space between content and the border of your box.

```
.toolbar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #444444;
  padding-top:10px;
}
#a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding:10px;
}
```